# Terraform: Passing variables while importing module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

After reading this https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables, I was certain that there are 3 ways to set variable value.

Recently I came across code in one our projects which passes variables while importing module.

```
module "robot_shell" {
  source = "./modules/xx_shell"

  xx_resource_name_prefix             = local.resource_name_prefix
  cloudwatch_log_group_retention_days = 30
  s3_expiration_days                  = 30
}
```

file in the module `./modules/xx_shell`

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "dest" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.dest.bucket
  rule {
    id     = "expire"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = var.s3_expiration_days
    }
  }
}
```

variable definition variables.tf

```
variable "s3_expiration_days" {
  type        = number
  description = "S3 bucket objects expiration days https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#days"
}
```

Why does terraform documentation does not talk about it? Or is this a old way which is not used anymore?

Comment: Can you please clarify your issue? What is so "strange" that you find in that code?

Comment: That usually either the variables are passed either through tfvars or command line or environment but using modules is something I have never seen in documentation or any other post on stack

Comment: @Marcin is this some kind of best practice to pass variables when using modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a **normal way** to pass variables to modules as you described. This is described in TF docs in:

- [Add module configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module-create#add-module-configuration)

The link that you provided in the question is about passing variables to root/parent module when you run `plan/apply`. But when you want to pass variables to sub-modules defined using `module` block, you pass them through `module` arguments.

Comment: Is it possible to follow you on some twitter or any other platform ( you can delete your comment for privacy later )

Comment: @JatinMehrotra At the moment, I don't really use other platforms then SO. Best way is to ping me through SO, if that's not an issue.

Comment: understood marcin